# How to import the python package from NFS share

Tags: python

Few my python packages are available in NFS share which gets mounted on my machine

```
Ex:
 mount server:/exports /localmount

python package module PATH: /localmount/dir1/dir2/mypackages/hub
```

When I try to import the package from "/localmount/dir1/dir2/mypackages/hub", it says.

```
ImportError: No module named localmount
```

But If change the directory to "/localmount" its working

Please note: All directories have `__init__.py` file recursively.

code snippet:

```
>>> from localmount.dir1.dir2.mypackages.hub import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named localmount.dir1.dir2.mypackages.hub import *
>>>
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir('/localmount')
>>>
>>> from dir1.dir2.mypackages.hub import *
>>>
```

Please advise how to import from package without moving the dir : localmount

Comment: The directories need to have an ```__init__.py``` file in them. They can be empty. That are there to tell Python that they are importable. This is definitely not practical. Best move is probably to copy the libraries to a directory under your home directory and import from there.

Comment: Thank you for the response, All directories have __init__.py file recursively. I guess NFS mounts needs to handled differently in case imports, still investigating.

Comment: How about making this nfs mounted package installable and then install it?

Comment: I found a workaround/solution to this issue that,
added the NFS path to sys.path, it got resolved.

Comment: With that, you should be able to remove the chain of ```__init__.py``` files. Glad you could find the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix :
Added the NFS mount path to `os.path`, the issue got resolved.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.append('/localmount/dir1/dir2/mypackage')
>>> from hub import p1
```